# Why I can't make any kind of join in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

When I'm trying to make any kind of join it gives me errors

How can I solve this problem

Here's my code because this problem make a hassle for me

it's annoying me because I don't know what my wrong

So, please may you guide me what I can do to make any kind of join in this query ?

```
Create Table Department (
dept_name varchar(100) Primary Key,
building varchar(100),
budget INT,
);


Create Table student (
ID INT Primary Key,
name varchar(100),
dept_name varchar(100),
tot_cred INT,

Foreign Key (dept_name) references Department
);

Create Table course (
course_id varchar(100) Primary Key,
title varchar(100),
dept_name varchar(100),
credits INT,
Foreign Key (dept_name) references Department
);

Create Table takes (
ID INT,
course_id varchar(100),
sec_id INT,
semester varchar(100),
year INT,
grade varchar(100),

Primary Key (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year)

);
 --inserting student values
Insert Into student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred) values (00128, 'Zhang', 'Comp.Sci', 102);
Insert Into student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred) values (12345, 'Shankar', 'Comp.Sci', 32);
Insert Into student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred) values (19991, 'Brandt', 'History', 80);
Insert Into student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred) values (23121, 'Chavez', 'Finance', 110);
Insert Into student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred) values (44553, 'Peltier', 'Physics', 56);
Insert Into student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred) values (45678, 'Levy', 'Physics', 46);
Insert Into student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred) values (54321, 'Williams', 'Comp.Sci', 54);
Insert Into student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred) values (55739, 'Sanchez', 'Music', 38);
Insert Into student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred) values (70557, 'Snow', 'Physics', 0);
Insert Into student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred) values (76543, 'Brown', 'Comp.Sci', 58);
Insert Into student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred) values (76653, 'Aoi', 'Elec.Eng', 60);
Insert Into student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred) values (98765, 'Bourikas', 'Elec.Eng', 98);
Insert Into student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred) values (98988, 'Tanaka', 'Biology', 120);

--inserting takes values
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (00128, 'CS-101', 1, 'Fall', 2009, 'A');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (00128, 'CS-347', 1, 'Fall', 2009, 'A-');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (12345, 'CS-101', 1, 'Fall', 2009, 'C');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (12345, 'CS-190', 2, 'Spring',2009, 'A');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (12345, 'CS-315', 1, 'Spring', 2010, 'A');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (12345, 'CS-347', 1, 'Fall', 2009, 'A');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (19991, 'HIS-351', 1, 'Spring', 2010, 'B');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (23121, 'FIN-201', 1, 'Spring', 2010, 'C+');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (44553, 'PHY-101', 1, 'Fall', 2009, 'B-');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (45678, 'CS-101', 1, 'Fall', 2009, 'F');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (45678, 'CS-101', 1, 'Spring', 2010, 'B+');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (45678, 'CS-319', 1, 'Spring', 2010, 'B');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (54321, 'CS-101', 1, 'Fall', 2009, 'A-');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (54321, 'CS-190', 2, 'Spring', 2009, 'B+');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (55739, 'MU-199', 1, 'Spring', 2010, 'A-');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (76543, 'CS-101', 1, 'Fall', 2009, 'A');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (76543, 'CS-319', 2, 'Spring', 2010, 'A');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (98765, 'CS-101', 1, 'Fall', 2009, 'C-');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (98765, 'CS-315', 1, 'Spring', 2010, 'B');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (98988, 'BIO-101', 1, 'Summer', 2009, 'A');
Insert Into takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade) values (98988, 'BIO-101', 1, 'Summer', 2010, 'null');

--inserting course values
Insert Into Course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits) values ('BIO-101', 'Intro to Biology', 'Biology', 4);
Insert Into Course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits) values ('BIO-301', 'Genetics', 'Biology', 4);
Insert Into Course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits) values ('BIO-399', 'Computational Biology', 'Biology', 3);
Insert Into Course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits) values ('CS-101', 'Intro to Computer Science', 'Comp.Sci', 4);
Insert Into Course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits) values ('CS-190', 'Game Design', 'Comp.Sci', 4);
Insert Into Course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits) values ('CS-315', 'Robotics', 'Comp.Sci', 3);
Insert Into Course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits) values ('CS-319', 'Image Processing', 'Comp.Sci', 3);
Insert Into Course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits) values ('CS-347', 'Database System Concepts', 'Comp.Sci', 3);
Insert Into Course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits) values ('EE-181', 'Intro to Digital System', 'Elec.Eng', 3);
Insert Into Course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits) values ('FIN-201', 'Investment Banking', 'Finance', 3);
Insert Into Course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits) values ('HIS-351', 'World History', 'History', 4);
Insert Into Course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits) values ('MU-199', 'Music Video Production', 'Music', 3);
Insert Into Course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits) values ('PHY-101', 'Physics Principles', 'Physics', 4);

--inserting department values

Insert Into Department(dept_name, building, budget) values ('Biology', 'Watson', 90000);
Insert Into Department(dept_name, building, budget) values ('Comp.Sci', 'Taylor', 100000);
Insert Into Department(dept_name, building, budget) values ('Elec.Eng', 'Taylor', 85000);
Insert Into Department(dept_name, building, budget) values ('Finance', 'Painter', 120000);
Insert Into Department(dept_name, building, budget) values ('History', 'Painter', 50000);
Insert Into Department(dept_name, building, budget) values ('Music', 'Packard', 80000);
Insert Into Department(dept_name, building, budget) values ('Physics', 'Watson', 70000);


Select name, dept_name

From student join Department

on student.dept_name=Department.dept_name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when I ran your query I received this error `ERROR:  column reference "dept_name" is ambiguous`

I'm not sure if this is your problem or just a typo, but to fix it you just need to specify which table you want to retrieve `dept_name` from like this:

```
select name, Department.dept_name                                                                                                                                                                          
from student join Department                                                                                                                                                                                    
on student.dept_name=Department.dept_name;
```

which returns:

```
   name   | dept_name 
----------+-----------
 Zhang    | Comp.Sci
 Shankar  | Comp.Sci
 Brandt   | History
 Chavez   | Finance
 Peltier  | Physics
 Levy     | Physics
 Williams | Comp.Sci
 Sanchez  | Music
 Snow     | Physics
 Brown    | Comp.Sci
 Aoi      | Elec.Eng
 Bourikas | Elec.Eng
 Tanaka   | Biology
```

Comment: @User2012384  Thank you dude for contributing in solve my problem

Comment: @AhmedHillal If this answer solved your question, you can select the green checkbox to the left of the answer.  If you found the answer helpful, you can click the up arrow.

Comment: @BenGlasser 

I'd like to ask you what if I forgot to add primary or foreign key
in my table 

what command I should use ?

Comment: @User2012384  what if I forgot to add primary or foreign key in my table what command I should use ?

Comment: @AhmedHillal use this to add a primary key to an existing table `ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD PRIMARY KEY (table_column);`

Comment: @BenGlasser Thanks man what about editing data type of attribute ?

Comment: @AhmedHillal `ALTER TABLE <table>
    ALTER COLUMN <column> SET DATA TYPE <data_type>` if you give me the requirements I can just write the thing for you.  I charge by the hour ;)

Comment: @BenGlasser Thank you very much for your effort

do you have file contains all these commands ?

may help me

Comment: @AhmedHillal I don't, but you can find anything on google ;)

Comment: @BenGlasser you are right ;) anyway thank you man

do you have facebook account I can contact with you ?

Comment: @BenGlasser Hello Man

I'd like to ask you

Can I make executable file and insert data like excel 

and make sql quaries written automatically ?


and also can I provide some thing like "Scanner Package " in "JAVA"  ?

Comment: @BenGlasser Hello Dude I need you help 

I want to insert date in my database 

and it requires from me to get date before specific date

to more clear for example:

show date before 2nd of August 2015

and I've used "varchar" when I entered date so, how to get after and before this date

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the dept_name, you have dept_name in Department and student

so, try changing your query, specify which dept_name you want:

```
Select a.name, b.dept_name

From student a join Department b 

on student.dept_name=Department.dept_name
```

By the way, I would suggest you to post your error message here so we can take a deeper look at the error.

Comment: I've tried you your code it 

come error message :-


Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 103
The multi-part identifier "student.dept_name" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 103
The multi-part identifier "Department.dept_name" could not be bound.

Comment: Are you using Master database? try changing the database to the database you want.

Comment: No I'm using particular database not master @User2012384

Comment: What table alias did you specify for student and department?

Comment: I changed the alias of student table and department table to a and b respectively

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you mean

Comment: Never mind, post your updated sql to the question and let me have a look

Comment: Your issue is that `on student.dept_name=Department.dept_name` won't work when you've aliased your tables.  You need `on a.dept_name=b.dept_name` instead.